# Any criterias when $0 of a Perl script becomes null?

Tags: perl, process

I am having a Perl script which internally uses dependent Perl modules from CPAN and my own project. I am using the `$0` (process script name) attribute value in my script. Strangely, this value suddently becomes NULL after some dependent API calls. I am not using `eval()` or `system()` in my process. Just a regular top-down running script. Any idea what could be the reason for the vanishing of `$0` value?

Comment: $0 can be modified - is it possible one of the API calls is assigning to it?

Comment: Running this one-liner produces a strange warning: `perl -lwe'print $0; undef $0;'` : First it prints `-e`, then it warns `Use of uninitialized value $0 in undef operator at -e line 1.`

Comment: Perl does not use the "null" concept, so by that statement, I guessed that you meant `undef`. But you should clarify what it really is. And you should also show the code that makes you think `$0` is undef.

Comment: The same problem for me. By the way, the `Tie::StdScalar` solution below prints nothing. Does it signify a Perl bug? (I think, without  a bug `STORE` would be called, but it doesn't.) Perl 5.16 on FreeBSD.

Comment: It may be related with this Perl bug: https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=123910

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Tie::StdScalar](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aStdScalar) to find out who changed `$0`.

```
{
   package Tie::Scalar::Croaker;
   use Tie::Scalar qw( );
   use Carp qw( confess );
   our @ISA = qw( Tie::StdScalar );
   sub FETCH { $0 }
   sub STORE { confess('$0 changed'); }
   tie($0, Tie::Scalar::Croaker::);
}
```